# Where is the manpage of otools gcc etc. on macOS?

Tags: macos, command-line

Many tools related with binaries, such otools, gcc, don't have manpages on my macOS (10.13.6). Is there a way to install the manpages for them?

Comment: [See this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23684642/how-to-fix-no-manual-entry-for-gcc). You can use `man clang`

Comment: Note gcc on current macOS is a link to clang i is not gcc If you are asked to use gcc the requester is not teaching you macOS things an so some things will just not work on macOS (There are reasons to use gcc but for advanced use only)

Comment: ALso `man otool` shows a page

Comment: I don't find the manpage for otool. In which directory is it installed in your Mac OS X? `$ man otool
No manual entry for otool`

Answer (score 2):

[This answer from stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23684642/how-to-fix-no-manual-entry-for-gcc) says that gcc is not installed by default on mac. Instead it installs clang and calls it gcc.

```
usxxplayegm1:~ grady$ which gcc
/usr/bin/gcc

usxxplayegm1:~ grady$ /usr/bin/gcc --version

Configured with: --prefix=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple LLVM version 5.1 (clang-503.0.38) (based on LLVM 3.4svn)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin13.0.2
Thread model: posix
```

you need `man clang`. Alternatively, if you want help regarding gcc, you can use `gcc --help`

Comment: I don't find the manpage for clang. In which directory is it installed in your Mac OS X? `$ man clang
No manual entry for clang`

Comment: @user1424739 - `clang` is there.  I just double checked with the command `man clang` and it brought up the man page - this is on a clean High Sierra install.

Comment: Could you check your output of `man -w clang`? Also, my machine was upgraded from a lower version OS. I am wondering that could be the reason.

Answer (score -1):

The manpage search path on macOS can be complicated. You need to set the pathname for all manpages in the MANPATH variable.

One way to find out where a man page is located is to use mdfind(1) to locate the directory that houses the man page. In this case, clang is a command line tool so the associated manpage will have a .1 suffix. Here's how to find it on your system.

```
mdfind clang.1
```

On my system this returns

```
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/share/man/man1/clang.1
```

To get these manpages you'll then need to add the directory

```
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/share/man
```

to your MANPATH.

Below is my MANPATH (which I set in ~/.bash_profile). Note that the "/usr/local/share/man" is where I store the manpages from my own projects; this is also the default location for [homebrew](https://brew.sh) packages.

```
export MANPATH=/usr/local/share/man:/usr/share/man:/Library/Apple/usr/share/man:/usr/lib/*/man:/usr/share/*/man:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/share/man/:/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/share/man:/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/share/man/
```